# How can i modify my date format like this: "month day, year"

Tags: reactjs, momentjs

i am getting a date with a format like this:

```
const momentDate = localDate(date)
return momentDate.format('LL')
```

in **english** i am geting good "december 5, 2023" but in **spanish**
that is returning me '5 de diciembre de 2023' i would like get "diciembre 5, 2023"

how can i get it in that format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "LL" format in Moment.js is locale-specific and provides a long date format which typically includes the day of the month, month name, and year in a format that is standard for the specified locale.

Instead try to customise the format like this

```
const momentDate = localDate(date);
return momentDate.format('MMMM D, YYYY');
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll find your answer here https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/

You can use the chart to determine exactly the format you want.

But also, consider that you probably don't want to add `moment` to any new projects if you can avoid it, based on https://momentjs.com/docs/#/-project-status/

Comment: in spanish is making wrong

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, but if it's regarding the translation, you can use `moment.locale` to set to spanish: https://momentjs.com/docs/#/i18n/